# Parallel for loop matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

Hi it's the first time I want to use the parallel toolbox from matlab. I have this loop

```
for y=1:size(pxyvector,1)
    if (strcmp(pxyvector{y,1}, emotionword))&&(strcmp(pxyvector{y,2},tweet{x}))
          pxyvector{y,3} = pxyvector{y,3} +1;
          invector = true;
    end
end
```

How would I go and make this work in a parallel `for`. I read the sliced variables part of matlab, but I don't get how I can do this here.

`pxyvector` is a 100000x3 cell array

`tweet{x}` is a string

`emotionword` is a string too.

`invector` is a value that is used later outside the loop.

So basically I compare the first value from a row of the pxyvector with the emotion word, and the second value from a row of the `pxyvector` to `tweet{x}`. If they are the same. The third value in the row gets incremented.

During the loop the same value cannot be incremented twice.

The problems in this for loop are that I need to change a variable that is used outside the loop too and increment a value.

Some data to play with : http://ojtwist.be/pxyvector.mat  (variable is pxyvector2 in this .mat file, so change that in the code, if you want to test it)

Comment: Well, which error you get when you try parfor? btw you can split the pxyvector and use a SIMD approach on different workers.

Comment: pxyvector is indexed in different ways, potentially causing dependencies between iterations. And invector is used after the parfor loop but its value is nondeterministic.  How ouwld SIMD approach work here ?

Comment: `pxyvector` seems fine to me as only one row is touched at a time, i.e., it should be fine to calculate it in parallel. However, `invector` is a problem. How about changing that line to `invector(y) = true;`? Then it should run in the `parfor` loop too. After the loop, just use `invector = any(invector);`.

Comment: Your second suggestion might be a solution to that line. But it still won't execute because the " pxyvector is indiced in different ways ..." error

Comment: Can you please change a little bit your code in order to have the same situation but allowing other people here to easily work on it?

Comment: You can use this code. I added a shorter version of my data here: http://ojtwist.be/pxyvector.mat . Feel free to work with that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem here is that matlab doesn't handle cell matrices as normal matrices (in fact a{1,:} doesn't behave as you expect).

AFAIK, to use `parfor` you need a different organization of data, specifically as a `Nx1` `cell` of `3x1` `cell` elements.

The following works, for instance

```
tot = size(pxyvector,1)
%%%%// just to reshape data correctly
pxvector_a = pxyvector;
pxyvector = cell(1,tot);
for i = 1:tot
   pxyvector{i} = {pxvector_a{i,1} pxvector_a{i,2} pxvector_a{i,3}};    
end
%%%%

 parfor y=1:tot
    if (strcmp(pxyvector{y}{1}, 'almost'))&&(strcmp(pxyvector{y}{2},'that'))
          pxyvector{y}{3} = pxyvector{y}{3} +1;
          invector = true;
    end
end
```

you can still use `smpd`, but your current organization of data will make the creation of proper distributed arrays hard.

Comment: @Ojtwist, likely a memory access problem: data distribution gets more random. Try to separate things so to have 3 (Nx1) cell arrays.